# Javascript if or switch statement to add a class

Tags: javascript

I am just trying to add a simple *class* to an element but I am not to sure if I would be better of using and if statement or switch.
I have compiled below my code using an if statement but would appreciate some help on converting it to a switch for testing purposes.

```
if (currentSlide === 0) {
  slide.classList.add('class0');
} else if (currentSlide === 1) {
    slide.classList.add('class1');
  } else if (currentSlide === 2) {
      slide.classList.add('class2');
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried in order to change this code to be based on a [`switch` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)? What went wrong?

Comment: I mean, in this situation I'd just do `slide.classList.add('class'+currentSlide)`...

Comment: The way this is written I'd suggest `slide.classList.add('class' + currentSlide)` would be easier, and more concise than either an `if` or a `switch`.

Comment: Switch is practically always more performant (fact), and easier to read (opinion) but as others have pointed out, would be easier and simpler to just use the iteration for what it is..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use switch case:

```
switch (currentSlide) {
    case 0:
        slide.classList.add('class0');
        break;
    case 1:
        slide.classList.add('class1');
        break;
    case 2:
        slide.classList.add('class2');
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

OR:

```
slide.classList.add('class' + currentSlide);
```

OR: use an Array...

```
var classes = ["class0", "class1", "class2"]
slide.classList.add(classes[currentSlide]);
```

Answer (score 2):

As your code stands, the ideal solution will be:

```
slide.classList.add('class'+currentSlide);
```

But if you really want to the conversion of the `if...else` to [`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch):

```
switch (currentSlide) {
  case 0:
    slide.classList.add('class0');
    break;
  case 1:
    slide.classList.add('class1');
    break;
  case 2:
    slide.classList.add('class3');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function addclass(class_nr) 


{Slide.classlist.add("class"+class_nr);}
```

Try to use functions and their params as much as you can, it will make the code more readbale and you will be able to use the same code in multiple places